# How to save a Sqlite3 database with .db extension in Node.Js

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I am working in Node.JS with the Sqlite3 module. As part of my project I need to export the database as 'postcard.db'. I am able to create the table, but I am having difficulty finding ways to save my database with this .db extension. Can someone highlight which commands I could use to do this to my database. This is how I initialized my database:

```
const sqlite = require('sqlite3').verbose(); 
var db = new sqlite.Database('./postcards.db');
```

Clearly the second line is incorrect as no .db file is created in my project

Answer (score 2):

`new sqlite.Database` will create the database if it does not exist. And when you close the handle it will be automatically saved. You don't have to do anything. Check this test file [here](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/blob/a8c34ea40132d343c4a9b2e6bf1adeeb9f8a0cf6/test/open_close.test.js):

```
describe('open and close non-existant database', function() {
    before(function() {
        helper.deleteFile('test/tmp/test_create.db');
    });

    var db;
    it('should open the database', function(done) {
        db = new sqlite3.Database('test/tmp/test_create.db', done);
    });

    it('should close the database', function(done) {
        db.close(done);
    });

    it('should have created the file', function() {
        assert.fileExists('test/tmp/test_create.db');
    });

    after(function() {
        helper.deleteFile('test/tmp/test_create.db');
    });
});
```

As you can see the test first deletes the file, then opens the database, closes the database then checks if the file exists or not then deletes the database.

So,

```
db = new sqlite3.Database('test/tmp/test_create.db', callback);
db.close(callback);
```

Should do what you are trying to achieve automatically.